# highcharts multi curved for different x value

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want to generate a graph of statistic with a plugin jquery for these informations:

[image]

So, I chould have 2 curved lines one for `"Envoi"` and one for `"Achat"`.

I tried with the plugin `highcharts`:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $('#container_highcharts').highcharts({
                    title: {
                        text: 'Statistique Mensuelle',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: '',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ["1","2","3","4",]  ,
                        labels: {
                            align: 'left'
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Nbre SMS'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: 'SMS'
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'middle',
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        line: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            },
                            enableMouseTracking: true
                        }
                    },
                    series: [
                              {
                        name: 'Envoi',
                        data: [

                        { name:'1' , y:300},
                        { name:'2' , y:200},
                        { name:'4' , y:650},
                    ]
                    }, {
                        name: 'Achat',
                        data: [
                            { name:'3' , y:600},
                            {name:'4' , y:500}
                        ]
                    }]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But the result of this script is on this photo:

[image]

But for the x values in the curve  "Achat" don't match the values in the table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by this format:

```
{ name:'11/2013' , y:300}
```

While you should be using timestamps for x-values:

```
{ x:1383264000000 , y:300}
```